# What is the time complexity of below code?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Can some one please let me know the time complexity of below code.

```
nums=[1,2,4,6,180,290,1249]
ll=[]
l=[]
for i in nums:
    for j in range(1,int(sqrt(i))+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            l.append(j)
    
    ll.append(l.copy())
    l.clear()
print(ll)
pass
```

Comment: What have you analyzed so far?

Comment: dunno brah. that looks like O(N*M) to me though.

Comment: Its not really N^2 though.  The inner for loop maxes out at `M` = the largest sqrt(largest value in nums).  There's also the factor K for the longest length of list l when l.copy() gets called, but that will always be smaller than M.
This feels more like O(N * M).  if the list nums has all of the numbers from 1-10000, then N dominates (M maxes at 100).  But if nums contains only a single very large int (say in the range of 2^63-1) then M dominates.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main operations that are going to determine the time complexity.

1. The outer loop `for i in nums` is O(N) where N = len(nums)
2. The inner loop `for j in range(1,int(sqrt(i))+1)`
3. Within the first loop we also have `ll.append(l.copy())`, where `l.copy()` is an O(k) operation where k == len(l)

Let N = len(nums), M = sqrt(max(nums)), and K = the length of the longest list `l` being copied.

As M and K are at the same level, this starts us at `O(N * (M+K))`
However, K is dependent on M, and will always be smaller (K is the  number of factors of i <= sqrt(i)), so we can effectively ignore it.

This results in the a complexity of O(N * M), where N = len(nums), and M = sqrt(max(nums))

Comment: Side note:  Is it intentional that the code in question only gets the factors <=sqrt(i)?  This only gets you half the factors. For example, if you one of the nums is 1,000,000, you're only getting 25 of the 49 factors.  You would also need to append `i // j` to get the remaining factors.